# Make a div's minimum width fit content?

Tags: html, css

I have a div that is normally set to take up 20% of the page's width, however, on a page where this 20% is not enough to display its content without overflowing, I would like it to take up the minimum amount of width necessary to fit the content. The content is not necessarily fixed-width, so I cannot simply use `min-width` with a hardcoded value in pixels.

I'd like to do this with pure CSS, if at all possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, what I would suggest is defining a **Breakpoint**. So you have to figure out on which point your width is not enough, and use a media query to overwrite CSS rules to fit different situations.

So you could do something like this if your page breaks for smaller screen widths than 720px:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 720px) {
    /* ... */
}
```

Then you can define a new `width` or `min-width` inside of this media query.